# Need to create always to div

Tags: html, css

I am going to make a website like this http://watcherboost.com/

SO i want to create middle menu for my website.so i need to create a div tag which is always top on following background:

This is the code i tried

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>

    <div id="top" style="background-color:#072530; height: 30px;margin-top: -10px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:initial">

    </div>

  </div>
</form>
<div style="height: 300px;background-color:  #0E5D7B; margin-top: 0px;">
</div>

<div style="background-color:#072530; height: 30px;margin-top: -10px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:initial">

</div>

<div style="height: 650px; background-color:  #C2C2C2; margin-top: 0px;">
</div>
<div style="background-color:#072530; height: 30px;margin-top: -10px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:initial">

</div>
<div style="height: 300px;background-color:  #0E5D7B; margin-top: 0px;">
</div>
<div style="background-color:#072530; height: 30px;margin-top: -10px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:initial">

</div>

<div id="middle" style="margin-left: 150px;margin-right:150px;margin-top:-250px;background-color:black"></div>
```

I want to get this last div (id =middle) to always top mode like upper website.
But unfortunately my div (id=middle) is not showed the page..

Please advice how to edit this code
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div is not showing up, because it doesn't contain any content. Add `height` property to its inline CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a div stay on top you should set:

```
position:fixed;
top:0px;
```

try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/TiG3R/ug4vvo48/

Comment: hi thanks for your code. could you tell me how to get this div to center...

Comment: you want all navbar at center or navbar text?!

Comment: I am going to put navbar and other things in this div,, so first i wanna center this div

Comment: check this: https://jsfiddle.net/TiG3R/ug4vvo48/1/ | Please accept the answer if it works for you